# I have to apply the to the columns of my dataset the clustering algorithm

Tags: python-3.x, dbscan

I have to apply the following to the columns of my dataset DF
clustering algorithm
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html
How can I do? Thanks

I write this code but when I sent it running with the complete dataset gives me output "MEMORYERROR"

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn import metrics
import sklearn.utils
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
#sklearn.utils.check_random_state(1000)
Clus_dataSet = df[['pickup_dt','pickup_lat', 'pickup_lon']]
Clus_dataSet = numpy.nan_to_num(Clus_dataSet)
Clus_dataSet = StandardScaler().fit_transform(Clus_dataSet)

# Compute DBSCAN
db = DBSCAN(eps=2, min_samples=2, metric='euclidean').fit(Clus_dataSet)
core_samples_mask = numpy.zeros_like(db.labels_, dtype=bool)
core_samples_mask[db.core_sample_indices_] = True
labels = db.labels_

# Number of clusters in labels, ignoring noise if present.
n_clusters_ = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)
n_noise_ = list(labels).count(-1)

print('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
print('Estimated number of noise points: %d' % n_noise_)

# Plot result
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Black removed and is used for noise instead.
unique_labels = set(labels)
colors = [plt.cm.Spectral(each)
          for each in numpy.linspace(0, 1, len(unique_labels))]
for k, col in zip(unique_labels, colors):
    if k == -1:
        # Black used for noise.
        col = [0, 0, 0, 1]

    class_member_mask = (labels == k)

    xy = Clus_dataSet[class_member_mask & core_samples_mask]
    plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=tuple(col),
             markeredgecolor='k', markersize=14)

    xy = Clus_dataSet[class_member_mask & ~core_samples_mask]
    plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=tuple(col),
             markeredgecolor='k', markersize=6)

plt.title('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What have you tried? We'll help if you get stuck. Show us some code.

Comment: I entered the code

Answer (score 0):

```
Clus_dataSet = df[['pickup_dt','pickup_lat', 'pickup_lon']]
Clus_dataSet = numpy.nan_to_num(Clus_dataSet)
Clus_dataSet = StandardScaler().fit_transform(Clus_dataSet)
```

This already sounds like a **really bad idea** to me. Latitude and longitude must not be standardized. Also, just mixing this with datetime will likely cause an undesirable bias of one versus the other. Instead you'll want to use generalized DBSCAN with *two* thresholds. One threshold on time, one on the *Haversine* distance of coordinates. Because Earth is not flat, and if you standardize this you even scale it different when going east vs. when going north. This does not make a lot of sense to do, right?

Also, the epsilon seems very large to me, while min samples is chosen too small (at 2, DBSCAN becomes a flat slice through single-link clustering).

As for scalability, the sklearn implementation of DBSCAN *differs* from the original DBSCAN in that it uses *much* more memory, in particular when the radius is set too high. Then sklearn can use up to O(n²) memory. You may want to try the OPTICS implementation instead (which really should use only O(n) memory) or use alternate DBSCAN implementation such as the one from ELKI.